# InstantiationException while instantiating inner class using reflection. Why?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, factory, inner-classes

i cant create B-Object, but why?

```
public class AFactory {

    public int currentRange;

    private abstract class A {
        protected final Object range = currentRange;

        public int congreteRange = 28;
    }

    public class B extends A {
        public int congreteRange = 42;
    }

    synchronized A createNew(Class<? extends A> clazz) throws Exception {
        // EDIT: there is accessible default constructor
        currentRange = clazz.newInstance().congreteRange;
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AFactory factory = new AFactory();
        System.out.println(factory.createNew(B.class).range);
    }
}
```

Exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: AFactory$B
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at AFactory.createNew(AFactory.java:15)
at AFactory.main(AFactory.java:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are trying to instantiate an *inner class*, which you can only access on an instance of the outer class. The constructor of the inner classes takes an implicit hidden `instance` of the enclosing class. You can see it by analyzing the byte code of this simple class:

```
public class Demo {
    class Test {
    }
}
```

Now, compile the code:

```
javac Demo.java
```

This will create two class files:

```
Demo.class
Demo$Test.class
```

Run the following command to see the byte code of `Demo$Test.class`:

```
javap -c . Demo$Test
```

You will get following result:

```
class Demo$Test {
  final Demo this$0;   

  Demo$Test(Demo);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_1
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:LDemo;
       5: aload_0
       6: invokespecial #2                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
       9: return
}
```

So, you see the constructor for the class? It takes `Demo` as parameter. So, there is no 0-arg constructor.

However, if you make your inner classes `static`, it would work, because then you don't need any instance of enclosing class to invoke inner class constructor.

**With `static` inner classes - Alternative:**

```
public class AFactory {

    public static int currentRange;

    private static abstract class A {
        protected final Object range = AFactory.currentRange;
    }

    public static class B extends A {
        public int congreteRange = 42;
    }

    synchronized A createNew(Class<? extends B> clazz) throws Exception {
        currentRange = clazz.newInstance().congreteRange;
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AFactory factory = new AFactory();
        System.out.println(factory.createNew(B.class).range);
    }
}
```

---

**With non-`static` inner classes - Final Code:**

If you don't want to make them `static`, then you would have to first create an instance of the enclosing class. And pass it to the constructor of the inner class. To get the constructor of the inner class, you can use [`Class#getDeclaredConstructor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredConstructor%28java.lang.Class...%29) method.

Now, you would have to modify your factory method to take a `Constructor` as parameter. Modify your code like this:

```
public class AFactory {

    public int currentRange;

    private abstract class A {
        protected final Object range = currentRange;
    }

    public class B extends A {
        public int congreteRange = 42;
    }

    synchronized A createNew(Constructor<? extends A> ctor) throws Exception {
        // Pass `this` as argument to constructor. 
        // `this` is reference to current enclosing instance
        return ctor.newInstance(this); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AFactory factory = new AFactory();

        // Get constructor of the class with `AFactory` as parameter
        Class<B> bClazz = B.class;
        Constructor<B> ctor = bClazz.getDeclaredConstructor(AFactory.class);

        System.out.println(factory.createNew(ctor));
    }
}
```

Comment: But i have already a instance of the outer class `new AFactory()`!

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis. That's static field now. I've changed it.

Comment: @Rohit Jain - Are you sure? I think that's ok to create instance of an inner class. It is public and it has an `AFactory`() instance to attach to.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis hm, we can make currentRange static, as long as the createNew is sychronized it might work.

Comment: @PeterRader Yeah you already have, but you are only accessing method on that instance. The constructor of inner classes takes the enlclosing instance as implicit parameter.

Comment: @PeterRader. Let me come up with some code that explains it in detail.

Comment: OH! Thats great in 2 ways: 1. This answer is exact. 2. this answer is easy to understand!

Comment: Ok, if i explicitly create a Default-Constructor for A or B, the default-constructor it will never ever been called directly, the constructor will always be called as a super of the hidden inner-class-constructor as long A or B is an inner class!

Comment: @PeterRader. Yes it's like that. You can now add a default constructor, and generate the byte code as in my answer, and you'll see the inner classes still has the same constructor

Comment: @PeterRader I've edited the answer to show you how to do it without `static inner` classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create A because you defined `clazz` to be of type that extends `B` and `A` doesn't extend `B` - it's the other way around (`B` extends `A`).

You should change the `createNew` signature to be:

```
synchronized A createNew(Class<? extends A> clazz) throws Exception
```

Comment: More over `clazz.newInstance()` is called twice.

Comment: i changed my question, same exception.

Answer (score -1):

Change your classes and variables to static.

```
public class AFactory {

public static int currentRange;

private static abstract class A {
    protected final Object range = currentRange;
}

public static class B extends A {

    public int congreteRange = 42;
}

synchronized A createNew(Class<? extends B> clazz) throws Exception {

    currentRange = clazz.newInstance().congreteRange;
    return clazz.newInstance();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    AFactory factory = new AFactory();
    System.out.println(factory.createNew(B.class).range);
}
}
```

and output is **42**.

Comment: *make them all static* - your default answer :D ? I like to forbid any other classes to make instances of A.

Comment: @PeterRader: "I like to forbid any other classes to make instances of A." What does that mean? Since B is public, even if B was a non-static inner class, anyone would be able to make an instance of it, as long as they have an instance of `AFactory`.

Comment: You are right, i ment i like to forbid any other classes to make instances of A without a instance of `AFactory`.