# Quartz job doesn't get executed

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I'm stuck with an attempt to fire a scheduled task every minute using spring 2.5 & quartz 1.6.2

Apparently the bean gets initiated and nicely prints out "works fine" to std out,
but the job does not seem to get executed - no string is printed out to log 
(no "hello quartz" appears in an output).

My xml file is:

```
<bean id="scheduler"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="UpdateDBWatchdog" class="com.db.update.task.watchdog.UpdateDBWatchdog"
    lazy-init="false" init-method="init">
    <constructor-arg ref="scheduler" />
</bean>
```

My code is:

```
import org.quartz.CronExpression;
import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;

public class UpdateDBWatchdog {

    private Scheduler scheduler;

    public UpdateDBWatchdog(Scheduler scheduler) {
        this.scheduler = scheduler;
    }

    public void init() {
        try {

            CronTrigger ct = new CronTrigger();
            ct.setName("dummyTriggerName");
            String expression = "* * * * * ?";

            boolean valid = CronExpression.isValidExpression(expression);
            if (valid) {
                ct.setCronExpression(expression);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }

            JobDetail job = new JobDetail();
            job.setName("dummyJobName");
            job.setJobClass(HelloJob.class);

            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, ct);
            scheduler.start();
            System.out.println("Works fine!");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private class HelloJob implements Job {
        @Override
        public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
            System.out.println("Hello Quartz!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a different expression? Like `0 * * * * ?`.

Comment: You always try creating a service and adding a @schedule annotation it is more easy and it is configurable by fixeddelay or cron expression using  a properties holder.

Comment: @mdrg yes i tried different ones the one you mentioned seems to get executed every hour

Comment: @vzamanillo, I'm not getting you; could you throw some examples and explain what you actually mean?

Comment: I think your cron expression is not correct, try with "0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *"

Comment: @vzamanillo  I tried different one and this one as well- It just doesn't go to an execute method

Comment: @tania did you get the solution for this problem? I am getting the same problem.

Comment: Not sure why this question got negative rating but I voted it positive as I faced exactly same issue and after declaring private inner class to public static inner class, my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you are getting a `java.lang.InstantiationException` because quartz are trying to instantiate an *inner class* ([explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137147/instantiationexception-while-instantiating-inner-class-using-reflection-why)).

Declare your `HelloJob` as *static* class in the outter class or get out from the `UpdateDBWatchdog` class and declare in his own file.